# How do I automatically add a row to an existing table on creation of new user in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to add a row to `photo_albums` table in my db containing the user ID for `current_user` and an album title "Posts Album" `before_create`.

- User has many PhotoAlbums
- PhotoAlbum belongs to User

I achieve something similar using `before_create :build_profile` to build an empty row for users personal information in my profiles table. This code is inside my user model.

I'd like to achieve something similar but in my `photo_albums` table. On creation of user create an album in the `photo_albums` table that will store all micropost related images. On creation of user I just need a row with `album title = "post album"` and their user id.

#### Model snippet

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :profile, :autosave => true
  has_many :photo_albums
  has_many :microposts

  before_create :build_profile
```

#### Controller's `create` action

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])   
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save 
      login @user
      UserMailer.join_confirmation(@user).deliver
      format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{root_path}'" } 
    else
      format.js { render :form_errors }
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this? Please notice a user has many photo albums so I can't use `build_photo_album`. I've read some info in the guides but still can't figure this out. Would appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no better solution then create a custom callback like this:

**UPDATED** (you even don't need to define `user_id => self.id` in `PhotoAlbum.create` params, it would be set automatically)

```
after_create :build_default_photo_album

def build_default_photo_album
  self.photo_albums << PhotoAlbum.create(:title => "post album")
end
```

Comment: I realised some moments ago that the user ID must have been set auto as it was being set for profiles table to and i hadn't set it manually any where so I assumed it was done automatically. Love this solution.. By the way it works with before_create, I didn't see a reason it wouldn't because it worked for creating a profile row for user too.